# iCalendar does not create an event for Sender's calendar

Tags: java, icalendar, google-workspace

I have an issue with Calendar. iCalendar not blocking the sender's calendar when I mentioned the sender in the attendee's list. Here is the approach which I am using.

Attendees: uday.a@domain.com, rana.b@domain1.com,venkatesh.k@domain.com

Organizer: recruitment.venkatesh.k@domain.in (which we are using to get calendar responses whenever attendees responded to the event then the calendar will the response).

Sender: venkatesh.k@domain.com

In the above case, Uday & Rana's calendar is blocked but not the Venkatesh. I have observed that it's not blocking the sender's calendar.  But for me it's required to block the sender calendar as well that's why I have added sender in the attendee's list. It's been more than a year which I am using this logic, till 16th-March-2020 it's working fine but from 17th March it's stopped blocking the sender's calendar and other functionalities are good. I don't know why it's got stopped working and there is no change in my code.

Note: I am using GSuite account for domain-level delegation and I am using GmailSender. I am preparing ICal as well.

Comment: Is this a programming problem? If so, would you show your code?

Comment: @halfer, I don't think so if the issue is with code then it should not work from day one. But it's worked till 17th March 2020(Note: I coded 2 years back)